# React - best way to link an entire element?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am wondering what the best way to link an entire element in React would be.

One thing I have tried is:

```
<article className="post" onClick={() => window.location = '/blog/' + this.props.post.slug}></article>
```

This method causes the whole page to reload.

Another method I have tried is using `Link` from `react-router-dom`:

```
<Link to={"/blog/" + this.props.post.slug}>
    <article className="post"></article>
</Link>
```

This method seems to work much better, though I'm not sure if wrapping the whole element in an `anchor` tag is best practice because I will have to override link styling on any text within the element. Is `Link` the best method for this or is there some other method I have not found yet? Is there a way to mimic the anchor tag behavior without actually wrapping the entire element in an anchor?

Comment: You *should* use an anchor for any link. If you must use an onClick handler, make sure you set the appropriate [ARIA attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_link_role). Remember that one big downside of making your own link is that you lose all the support browsers/a11y tech have for links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `this.props.history`

```
<article className="post" onClick={() => this.props.history.push(`/blog/${this.props.post.slug}`)}></article>
```

If the component rendering the above is not being rendered by a route, then use the `withRouter` HOC, provided by the `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 1):

2nd method is better.
We often use this technique for logos as folllows.
As long as react is generating simillar markup you should be good.
This is good for WCAG also.

```
<a  target="_blank" href="https://www.wikipedia.org">
  Wikipedia
  <img alt="(opens in new tab)" src="newtab.svg">
</a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0):

Link is a really good option; however, if you don't want to modify the CSS, you have various options:

#### Use the newly added useHistory hook

> This was  introduced in `react-router-dom` v5.1, so if you are in an older version update or check the next option.

You can use this hook on any component that is rendered by a `Route`:

```
import {
  useHistory,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";

const Blog = ({ post: { slug } }) => {
  const { push } = useHistory();

  return (
    <article className="post" onClick={() => push("/blog/" + slug)}></article>
  );
};
const App = () => (
  // ... get posts, etc.

  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/shop">Shop</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route
          path="/blog"
          component={props => <Blog post={post} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route path="/shop" component={Shop} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
);
```

#### Create history object and change the url from there

```
// See that we don't use BrowserRouter here
import { Router, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const Blog = ({ post: { slug } }) => {
  const { push } = history;

  return (
    <article className="post" onClick={() => push("/blog/" + slug)}></article>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  // ... get posts, etc.

  <div className="App">
    <Router history={history}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/shop">Shop</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route
          path="/blog"
          component={props => <Blog post={post} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route path="/shop" component={Shop} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
);
```

This is the most versatile approach since you can use it in components that are not included inside a `Route`, and pretty much anywhere. It is a good approach to declare it inside utils or helpers folder and export it for this reason (remember pass the `history` object to the `Router`).